# Easy-Webpack unknown property in configuration object

Tags: webpack, aurelia, easy-webpack

I am trying to learn easy-webpack and so I have started with a minimum project aurelia project setup.

I get the following error when running webpack.

**Run:** `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

**Error:**

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'metadata'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           metadata: ...
         }
       })
     ]
```

I do not see any reference to metadata in my webpack file and have no idea what is causing the error.

These are my configuration files

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "AureliaSpa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-event-aggregator": "^1.0.1",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "^1.1.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-history-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "aurelia-loader-webpack": "^2.1.0",
    "aurelia-logging-console": "^1.0.0",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-polyfills": "^1.2.0",
    "aurelia-route-recognizer": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-router": "^1.2.1",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "^1.3.0",
    "aurelia-templating-resources": "^1.3.1",
    "aurelia-templating-router": "^1.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@easy-webpack/core": "2.0.1",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "aurelia": {
    "build": {
      "includeDependencies": "aurelia-*"
    }
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.vendor.js:**

```
var path = require('path');

var common = {
  entry: {
    vendor: [
        'aurelia-event-aggregator',
        'aurelia-fetch-client',
        'aurelia-framework',
        'aurelia-history-browser',
        'aurelia-logging-console',
        'aurelia-pal-browser',
        'aurelia-polyfills',
        'aurelia-route-recognizer',
        'aurelia-router',
        'aurelia-templating-binding',
        'aurelia-templating-resources',
        'aurelia-templating-router',
        'bootstrap',
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'jquery'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: '[name]_[hash]'
  }
};

var generateConfig = require('@easy-webpack/core').generateConfig;

var config = generateConfig(common);

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: The easy-webpack you import has it - https://github.com/easy-webpack/core/blob/master/src/index.ts

Comment: @MukeshSoni So why am I getting the error?